# Why is RethinkDB very slow?

Tags: go, rethinkdb

I am getting started with RethinkDB, I have never used it before. I give it a try together with [Gorethink](https://github.com/dancannon/gorethink) following this [tutorial](https://www.compose.io/articles/go-rethinkdb-and-changefeeds-part-1/).

To sum up this tutorial, there are two programs:

The first one updates entries infinitely.

```
for {
    var scoreentry ScoreEntry
    pl := rand.Intn(1000)
    sc := rand.Intn(6) - 2
    res, err := r.Table("scores").Get(strconv.Itoa(pl)).Run(session)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = res.One(&scoreentry)
    scoreentry.Score = scoreentry.Score + sc
    _, err = r.Table("scores").Update(scoreentry).RunWrite(session)
}
```

And the second one, receives this changes and logs them.

```
res, err := r.Table("scores").Changes().Run(session)

var value interface{}

if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
for res.Next(&value) {
    fmt.Println(value)
}
```

In the statistics that RethinkDB shows, I can see that there are 1.5K reads and writes per second. But in the console of the second program, I see 1 or 2 changes per second approximately.

Why does this occur? Am I missing something?

Comment: you should mark mlucy's answer as correct :D

Answer (score 4):

This code:

```
r.Table("scores").Update(scoreentry).RunWrite(session)
```

Probably doesn't do what you think it does.  This attempts to update every document in the table by merging `scoreentry` into it.  This is why the RethinkDB console is showing so many writes per second: every time you run that query it's resulting in thousands of writes.

Usually you want to update documents inside of ReQL, like so:

```
r.Table('scores').Get(strconv.Itoa(pl)).Update(func (row Term) interface{} {
  return map[string]interface{}{"Score": row.GetField('Score').Add(sc)};
})
```

If you need to do the update in Go code, though, you can replace just that one document like so:

```
r.Table('scores').Get(strconv.Itoa(pl)).Replace(scoreentry)
```

Comment: As you say, merging the two queries into one made the performance scale! `r.Table("scores").Get(strconv.Itoa(pl)).Update(map[string]interface{}{"Score": r.Row.Field("Score").Add(sc)}).RunWrite(session)`

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why it is quite that slow, it could be because by default each query blocks until the write has been completely flushed. I would first add some kind of instrumentation to see which operation is being so slow. There are also a couple of ways that you can improve the performance:

1. Set the `Durability` of the write using `UpdateOpts`

   ```
   _, err = r.Table("scores").Update(scoreentry, r.UpdateOpts{
       Durability: "soft",
   }).RunWrite(session)
   ```
2. Execute each query in a goroutine to allow your code to execute multiple queries in parallel (you may need to use a pool of goroutines instead but this code is just a simplified example)

   ```
   for {
       go func() {
           var scoreentry ScoreEntry
           pl := rand.Intn(1000)
           sc := rand.Intn(6) - 2
           res, err := r.Table("scores").Get(strconv.Itoa(pl)).Run(session)
           if err != nil {
               log.Fatal(err)
           }

           err = res.One(&scoreentry)
           scoreentry.Score = scoreentry.Score + sc
           _, err = r.Table("scores").Update(scoreentry).RunWrite(session)
       }()
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, the other answer is also correct, but it improved the performance from 2 update/s to 20 update/s. I wrote 1000 routines which infinitely update the random row with the query I commented in the other answer. Now yes, the iterator of changes prints 1000 change/s approximately.